# cobertura maven pluginGenerate aggregate reports does not work

Tags: maven, cobertura

I discovered generating aggregate reports in multi-module projects only works if the maven aggregator pom project is also the parent project for sub modules. This really does not work for a lot enterprise level projects in which maven aggregator is not always the parent.

Really appreciate any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cobertura is an inactive project.  Check out JaCoCo as a viable replacement, and it supports aggregate.

But if the issue is related to the NPE you get, check out this: https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MCOBERTURA-151.  We're using 2.5.1 of that plugin w/ that patch applied and it allows us to build using aggregate, but the output isn't really aggregate.

Comment: are you sure that JaCoCo supports aggregate in maven? Based this article: http://www.lordofthejars.com/2012/07/jacoco-in-maven-multi-module-projects.html, it is not supported at all.

Comment: Depends on your expectations from aggregate. What I want is to be able to look at the entire multi-module project (jars, wars, etc) all on one single report.  With cobertura, I have to look at each module independently.  With JaCoCo, this is supposed to work based on something I read (can't find atm).  But we're currently using Sonar as the workaround for this.